# Voicemail Implementation for Incoming calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I know that voicemail is implemented via the `RECORD` twiml verb, but I want it run conditionally depending on whether the call was declined, not answered. Is this doable?

Comment: I think this may be possible via action property Dial verb, on action request I can probably detect if the phone was not answered and respond with voicemail twiml code. is this correct way to handle this?

Comment: I got reassurance that this solution will probably work from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463312/twilio-twiml-dont-record-after-client-hangs-up?rq=1